# PHP - Get week in year with day starting from Saturday

Tags: php, timestamp

I know I could use `date("W",$timestamp)` to get the number of week in the year. But the week starts on Monday. Is there any way which I could get the number of week in year with the week starting on Saturday?

Comment: I can understand if you want to start the week with `sunday` but why is that important to start with `saturday`, why do you want your own weeknumber count?

Comment: I would guess in Islam, as Friday is our Sunday so Saturday is our Monday

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IntlCalendar` class (install [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) extension)

```
$cal = IntlCalendar::createInstance();
$cal->set(2013, 5 /* June */, 30); // A Sunday
$cal->setFirstDayOfWeek(IntlCalendar::DOW_SATURDAY);
echo IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($cal, 'w');
```

Comment: I ran your script, it echos 270216 for the week of year. How could that be correct?

Comment: Alright I changed it to "w" in the second parameter of formatObject and it worked. It was a bit confusing. Thanks.